# How can I move this psql code run by bash into a regular .sql file?

Tags: postgresql, bash, psql

I am in the process of converting unnecessary shell scripts to hydrate a database in a Docker Container by moving them to an init file I plan to load into the init directory from the postgres image.

I am stuck on what this shell script

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "test" <<-EOSQL
CREATE or replace FUNCTION public.user_session_register(u_id integer, ip text DEFAULT NULL::text, path text DEFAULT NULL::text)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS \$\$
        BEGIN
            RETURN true;
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RETURN false;
        END
    \$\$;
```

I would like to understand what it is doing and how I can convert this to a standard query in my .sql file.

Comment: It's defining a stored function in the Postgres database.

Comment: There should be a line with `EOSQL` after the function definition.

Comment: You should be able to copy everything between the `psql` and `EOSQL` lines into a `.sql` line, and replace `\$` with `$`.

Comment: "Please explain this code" questions are as a general rule too broad to be on-topic, unless there's a _very_ specific question showing what research you've done, describing exactly what you do already understand and what's still unclear, etc. (On reading, I think you _do_ have a specific question here, and I've edited the title to try to better ask it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does exactly what it looks like it's doing: It defines a SQL function inside the database, or updates it with a new definition if it already exists. As [questions asking code to be explained are too broad to be on-topic here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) unless they show substantial research and identify a specific, narrow question, I won't go into this further.

---

The only change you need to be able to copy the body of the heredoc (the lines after `<<-EOSQL` and before `EOSQL`) into a .sql file is to change `\$\$` to just `$$` in both places where it's present.

By the way, the bash code only requires that escaping because the script uses an unquoted heredoc sigil. If it used `<<-'EOSQL'` instead of `<<-EOSQL`, the shell script could use regular `$$`s and you wouldn't need to change anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, yea changing it to this worked in my init file

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION public.user_session_register(u_id integer, ip text DEFAULT NULL::text, path text DEFAULT NULL::text)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
        BEGIN
            RETURN true;
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RETURN false;
        END
    $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "test" <<-EOSQL
```

for

```
cat <<-EOSQL
```

you'll get the sql code without the escapes.

To capture redirect this output to another file, you can execute this code in a subshell:

```
(cat <<-EOSQL
CREATE or replace FUNCTION public.user_session_register(u_id integer, ip     text DEFAULT NULL::text, path text DEFAULT NULL::text)
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS \$\$
    BEGIN
        RETURN true;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN false;
    END
\$\$;
EOSQL
) > sql.sql
```